# special character and parsing BUG - Bashscript

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

```
Failed to parse arguments: Argument to "--command/-e" is not a valid command: Text ended before matching quote was found for ". (The text was '"cpulimit')
```

this is what i get when i run the following script in terminal

```
    #!/bin/bash
read -p "Which program u want to limit its processes?" ProgrameName
read -p "Which limitation percentage u want for it ?" limitationPercentage  

getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram=$( ps -e | grep "$ProgrameName" | awk '{print $1;}')
for i in $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram
   do
    gnomeTab+="  --tab -e \"cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage \" "  
   done

gnome-terminal $gnomeTab
```

he cant parse the escape character "\" which it has to be used because  of  the  double quote in line 8 `gnomeTab+="  --tab -e \"cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage \" "`,so is there  a solution to use the double quote as they are mandatory to be used after `--tab -e " some commands "` and not to get the problem of parsing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the very first line to

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

to make the shell show you how it interprets arguments.

Rather than escaping (which leads to `eval`), you should use arrays to accumulate options:

```
for i in $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram ; do
    gnomeTab+=(--tab -e "cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage")  
done

echo "${gnomeTab[@]}"
```