# Start new gnome-terminal with several tabs and wait after command is run

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, zsh

I want to start a new gnome-terminal window with some command in multiple tabs. [Based to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application):

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "FOO" -e "/bin/zsh -i -c 'cd $(pwd); zsh -i'" \
               --tab -t "XYZ" -e "/bin/zsh -i -c 'cd $(pwd); tail -f /var/log/dmesg; zsh -i'"
```

The problem I'm facing is that after I <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> the blocking `tail -f` tab just quits and disappears. Though, I'd like it to stay open and possibly inspect the past output.

Somehow my guess is that some parent gets the `SIGINT` and quits it all together instead of sending it to the `tail` command.

For instance, a simple `sleep` works just fine:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "FOO" -e "/bin/zsh -i -c 'cd $(pwd); zsh -i'" \
               --tab -t "XYZ" -e "/bin/zsh -i -c 'cd $(pwd); sleep 3; zsh -i'"
```

This will keep both tabs open with a prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zsh`'s `trap` builtin (the `trap` builtin is also present in `bash`):

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "FOO" -e "zsh" \
--tab -t "XYZ" -e "zsh -c 'trap \"zsh\" 2; tail -f /var/log/dmesg'"
```

Or:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "FOO" -e "zsh" \
--tab -t "XYZ" -e "zsh -c 'trap \"zsh\" SIGINT; tail -f /var/log/dmesg'"
```

It looks like you're running this from `sh`. Some side notes:

- `zsh` in your installation is in `/bin` (hence in `path`) already, so all you need to spawn a `zsh` shell is `zsh`;
- `zsh` runs interactively by default, so probably all you need to spawn an interactive `zsh` shell is to run `zsh`;
- `zsh` is smart enough to read `pwd` by default, so probably all you need to spawn an interactive `zsh` shell in the same working directory of your `sh` instance is to run `zsh`;

The problem, as you thought, is the SIGINT signal, which is propagated to all the processes in the same process group of the process receiving the signal.

Using `trap 'zsh' 2` / `trap 'zsh' SIGINT` the current `zsh` instance is set to spawn another `zsh` instance upon the reception of a SIGINT signal, which bypasses the problem.

You may also make the `zsh` instance "immune" to multiple signals by listing them space-separated in the arguments:

```
trap 'zsh' 1 2 3 [...]
```

Or:

```
trap 'zsh' SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT [...]
```

You can print an ordered list all of all available signals by running `kill -l`:

```
% kill -l
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
```